# Angular directive manual compile in link function + transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm in need of doing transclusion together with manual compilation in link function and I'm wondering if there is a better way than what I'm pasting below as "Dynamic". It seems to be working but I'm not sure what are the consequences of removing `ng-transclude` attribute and I'm removing it due to Angular complaining to `Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <div ng-transclude="">`.

Bottom-line is that I need to provide different templates for different instances of this directive with fallback to generic ones.

I can't use compile part. Here I have just simple example but I have also other cases with big link function that I would rather don't want to convert as this should be just "golden bullet" type of adjustment.

This little guy can be found here https://github.com/institut-de-genomique/Ultimate-DataTable/blob/master/src/directives/udt-form.js in original form.

#### Original

```
angular.module('ultimateDataTableServices')
  .directive('udtForm', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace:true,
      transclude:true,
      templateUrl:'udt-form.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      }
    };
  });
```

#### Dynamic

```
angular.module('ultimateDataTableServices')
  .directive('udtForm', ['$compile', '$templateCache', function ($compile, $templateCache) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude:true,
      link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls, transclude) {
        var tplName = 'udt-form.html',
          tplPath = scope.udtTable.configMaster.templates[tplName] || scope.udtTable.configMaster.templatesMaster[tplName] || tplName,
          elem = angular.element($templateCache.get(tplPath));

        elem.find('[ng-transclude]').removeAttr('ng-transclude').append(transclude());

        element.replaceWith($compile($templateCache.get(tplPath))(scope));
      }
    };
  }]);
```

TIA!

Comment: this may be helpful-   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760223/angularjs-directive-template-with-ng-transclude-cannot-be-compiled